# How can I access to a specific values in a JSON Response with retrofit in android?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I have a JSON response from a marvel api, i can get the copyright info from it that is in the first level, here is the response to the service:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Ok",
    "copyright": "© 2019 MARVEL",
    "attributionText": "Data provided by Marvel. © 2019 MARVEL",
    "attributionHTML": "<a href=\"http://marvel.com\">Data provided by Marvel. © 2019 MARVEL</a>",
    "etag": "a1d8666dc86abda3bd2edf99d09446da82626c4b",
    "data": {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 20,
        "total": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "results": [
            {
                "id": 1009664,
                "name": "Thor",
                "description": "As the Norse God of thunder and lightning, Thor wields one of the greatest weapons ever made, the enchanted hammer Mjolnir. While others have described Thor as an over-muscled, oafish imbecile, he's quite smart and compassionate.  He's self-assured, and he would never, ever stop fighting for a worthwhile cause.",
.
.
.
}
```

I have my getters and setters like this:

```
private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String thumbnail;

    private String copyright;

    public Heroe() {}


    public Heroe(String copyright, int id, String name, String description, String thumbnail) {
        this.copyright = copyright;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
```

but i want to get the result from the data. to get the id, name, and description, here is my code:

[Android response service from MARVEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tP8b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Since the json response has a child node try to Create a custom response like

**`HeroResponse.java`**

```
class HeroResponse {
    private int code;
    private String status;
    //.. other variables
    @SerializedName("data")
    private Hero data

    //.. Getter and setter
}
```

**`Hero.java`**

```
class Hero {
    private int offset;
    private int limit;
    //.. other variables
    @SerializedName("results")
    private HeroDetail results

    //.. Getter and setter
}
```

**`HeroDetail.java`**

```
class HeroDetail {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description

    //.. Getter and setter
}
```

then on your retrofit call

```
heroeCall.enqueue(
  //..
  public void onResponse(Call<HeroResponse> call, Response<HeroResponse> response)  {
     HeroResponse resp = response.body();
     resp.copyright
     resp.data.offset
     resp.data.results.id
  }
)
```

Also don't forget to implement the `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'` in your app build.gradle if you want to use the annotation `SerializedName`

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

First create getter() and setter() methods in model class

Example :-

```
public class RetroPhoto {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("item")
    public Item a;

    public RetroPhoto(Integer albumId, Integer id, String title, String     url, String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.albumId = albumId;
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Item getItem11() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setItem11(Item item11) {
        this.a = item11;
    }

    public class Item{
       @SerializedName("id_item")
       private String idItem;
       @SerializedName("id_subcategory")
       private String idSubcategory;

       public String getIdItem() {
        return idItem;
       }

       public void setIdItem(String idItem) {
        this.idItem = idItem;
       }

       public String getIdSubcategory() {
        return idSubcategory;
       }

       public void setIdSubcategory(String idSubcategory) {
        this.idSubcategory = idSubcategory;
       }
    }
}
```

How to get idSubcategory :-

```
RetroPhoto.Item ri = response.getItem11();
String idSubcategory = ri.getIdSubcategory();
```